# Calling a module subroutine using a fully qualified name

Tags: module, raku

I created a simple test module **`./mods/My/Module.pm6`**:

```
unit module My::Module;
use v6;

sub hello () is export {
    say "Hello";
}
```

Then, I have a test script **`./p.p6`**:

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl6

use v6;
use My::Module;

My::Module::hello();
```

Then I set `PERL6LIB` to include the folder **`./mods`**, and then run the script:

```
$ ./p.p6 
Could not find symbol '&hello'
  in block <unit> at ./p.p6 line 7
```

However, if I replace the line `My::Module::hello()` in the script with `hello()` it works fine. What am I missing here?

Comment: Could it be that `sub`s are by default `my`, and thus not visible with their full name to the outside world.  Even though they are exported?  Compare `class A { sub B() { say "B" } }; A::B()` with `class A { our sub B() { say "B" } }; A::B()`

Comment: @ElizabethMattijsen That seems to be the case! Changing the declaration in the module to  `our sub hello () ...` seems to solve the problem..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you export hello you can simply use it

```
use v6;
use lib <lib>; # hint: no need to tinker with the environment
use My::Module;

hello();
```

If you really WANT to use a fully qualified name, you have to use the our keyword.

```
our sub hello () is export {
    say "Hello";
}
```